# asked about BigQuery limitation

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a system have 4 file log with total size >= 500TB.
I want create 1 dataset and 4 table in dataset (1 table >= 100TB).
With this information, Can doing it with bigquery?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Yes, you can. BigQuery has customers using petabytes of data.

Comment: Hi @Pentium10, my solution is using Azure. You know it?

Comment: I'd to know if you have compared prices

Comment: No, my solution for data more 500TB. But Azure just support max storage 2.4TB for one account Azure. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you check the product overview [[1]](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/) you can see that, as @Pentium10 told you, BigQuery  has a Petabyte scale:

> **Petabyte scale**
>
> BigQuery is fast and easy to use on data of any size. With BigQuery you’ll get great performance on your data, while knowing you can scale seamlessly to store and analyze petabytes more without having to buy more capacity.